# Simplify while loop in R

Tags: r, loops

how do I simplify this while loop? It doesn't seem to work when I put != 2 && 3 && 12.

Thank you

```
while (sum(diceRoll) != 2 && sum(diceRoll) !=3 && sum(diceRoll) !=12)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you provide the code that goes before/in the `while` loop? Because from the example it is not clear why this would not work. For example, this works fine: `x <- 11 ; while (x != 2 && x !=3 && x !=12) print(1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `%in%` operator, you could replace

```
while (sum(diceRoll) != 2 && sum(diceRoll) !=3 && sum(diceRoll) !=12)
```

by

```
while (!(sum(diceRoll) %in% c(2,3,12)))
```

The problem with your proposed solution is that `2 && 3 && 12` evaluates to `TRUE` so

```
while (sum(diceRoll) != 2 && 3 && 12)
```

parses as

```
while (sum(diceRoll) != TRUE)
```

which is functionally equivalent to

```
while (sum(diceRoll) != 1)
```

which is clearly not the intended meaning.